# similarity index in a list of character vectors

Tags: r, similarity

I have a list that looks like this one:

```
$`264`
[1] "CHAMP1" "MAP1S"  "PRRC1"  "TUT1"   "CDK12" 

$`265`
[1] "TUT1"   "PRRC1"  "CHAMP1" "MAP1S"

$`266`
[1] "REPS1"  "CHAMP1" "PRRC1"  "TUT1"   "MAP1S" 

$`267`
[1] "G3BP1"  "TUT1"   "PRRC1"  "CHAMP1" "MAP1S" 

$`268`
[1] "TUT1"   "CHAMP1" "PRRC1"  "MAP1S"  

$`269`
[1] "DDB1"   "CHAMP1" "TUT1"   "PRRC1"  "MAP1S"
```

Is there any `package` or function to calculate the similarity among the different list components?

Many thanks

Comment: Please be more specific.  Do you want the similarity across all of the the list elements? Or similarity only between the individual elements of each list element?  Sorry if that sounds confusing.

Comment: I would like to the similarity across the list elements, something like: `intersect(list[[1]], list[[2]])/union(list[[1]], list[[2]]`, hope it is clearer now

Comment: NO. Not clear. What resutl do you want to see from the data you presented?

Comment: This should be closed as you're asking for a package suggestion.  Have a look at the tm package and the `dissimilarity` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any packages, but this implements your own metric (from your comment):

```
siml  <- function(x,y) {
  length(intersect(lst[[x]],lst[[y]]))/length(union(lst[[x]],lst[[y]]))
}
z      <- expand.grid(x=1:length(lst),y=1:length(lst))
result <- mapply(siml,z$x,z$y)
dim(result) <- c(length(lst),length(lst))
result
#       [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4] [,5]  [,6]
# [1,] 1.000  0.8 0.667 0.667  0.8 0.667
# [2,] 0.800  1.0 0.800 0.800  1.0 0.800
# [3,] 0.667  0.8 1.000 0.667  0.8 0.667
# [4,] 0.667  0.8 0.667 1.000  0.8 0.667
# [5,] 0.800  1.0 0.800 0.800  1.0 0.800
# [6,] 0.667  0.8 0.667 0.667  0.8 1.000
```

This is a (slightly) more efficient way to do the same thing:

```
result <- sapply(lst,function(x) 
            sapply(lst,function(y,x)length(intersect(x,y))/length(union(x,y)),x))
```